# store variable value for 24 hrs only

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, jdo

I need a way ,so i keep value of variable store in a database of Google appengine for 24 hrs and then it is destroy automatically .
Is there any way,and some other way please.i need code explanation in java.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can store your data in entities in Google App Engine Datastore, and have a cron script that will delete them every 24 hours.

For more information about datastore, take a look at [Storing data in Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/), while for details on cron jobs on App Engine take a look at [Scheduled Tasks With Cron for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

Add the entity, and then immediately create a taskqueue task that will execute with an eta of 24 hours and delete the entity using its ID (passed as a TQ param). This will ensure a minimum of 24 hours to deletion. However if the taskqueue scheduler does not immediately pick up the eta-scheduled task, your delete may happen a bit after 24 hours. (This could be mitigated somewhat by using a dedicated, very high-rate TQ solely for this task.) Very straightforward approach downgraded by the "fuzzy 24+ hours until delete" issue -- although the cron job approach will also have some fuzziness depending on how frequently the cron runs. -stevep

re: code samples try the docs...
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/

Answer (score 0):

You can also store the Entities in the Memcache with a 24h timeout. This will be a very timely-accurate deletion, done automatically by the memcache itself. Not recommended if the values you store are critical for the use case. Check the memcache's SLA!

If the data is critical but the precision of the 24h delay not, I would save the Entities to the datastore normally, but with a timestamp (java.util.Date) field populated uppon Entity construction. Then run a backend task once an hour to search the Entities to delete. This would be the less ressource-consuming variant, but your entities will be deleted if they are 24:00:00.0000-24:59:59:9999 old (depending to the time at wich your task runs).

To have precisely deleted entities you will need to run your script once a minute or once a second, but then it could become really heavy if many indexes have to be updated in case of deletion. It could lead to other issues and depending to your data model, you will probably need to start using transactions.